# Crash in iOS 9 when setting Image as UIButton background image

Tags: objective-c, ipad, crash, uibutton, ios9

I have crash issue with iOS 9. if I set an image as Background image of UIButton. The same was working fine in iOS 8.

Here is the code:

```
    [clickButton setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But, If i modify it with

```
    [clickButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

App is not crashing but losing the button image.

Image shows the stack trace of crash [image: Stack trace]

I tried lot to resolve this issue but could not get any luck. It is very strange.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is that button on a strong property tho? If not, is it an IBOutlet? Is your image retained? Please give us more info.

Comment: where are you calling this code?

Comment: I am creating custom button at run time as i need to show n number of image with some dynamic frame value. I am displaying these  button image on PDF page that inherited from UIView class. For pdf kind of work i used VFR reader. Image is not getting retained.

Comment: UIButton *clickButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
NSData *dataElement = [Base64 decode:[dict valueForKey:@“ImageEncode"]];
UIImage* dataImage = [UIImage imageWithData:dataElement];                            
clickButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[clickButton setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:clickButton];
clickButton = nil;